# How to connect Contact Form 7 with Google Form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've read a tutorial how to do this. They said put this code in the **function.php** file.
I've tried it, when I sent a form, it sent a mail to me to notified this form was sent, but I didn't receive in Google Form.

I want to know if this code is correct or not. And are there any document how to connect Contact Form 7 with Google Form?

Sorry if the word is hard to understand, English is not my mother language.

Thank you.

```
function pveser_sent_contact_to_drive( $contact_form )
{

$form_id = $contact_form->id;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission )
{
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

if ($form_id==698)
{

$fields = array(
'entry.359835661'=>urlencode($posted_data['your-name']),
'entry.359835662'=>urlencode($posted_data['your-email']),
'entry.359835663'=>urlencode($posted_data['your-phone']),
'entry.359835663'=>urlencode($posted_data['your-note'])
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"UTF-8");

$url=utf8_encode('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScZ3lHLjJ-fkre90TcUQUsiUUL0lP5El0clkDKKoHQQ7iaZlA/formResponse');
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
}

}

}//End contact form

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'pveser_sent_contact_to_drive' );
```

`$form_id==698`: id of form Contact Form 7

`'entry.359835661'`: name attribute of a field in Google Form

`['your-name']`: name of its field in Contact Form 7

`utf8_encode('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScZ3lHLjJ-fkre90TcUQUsiUUL0lP5El0clkDKKoHQQ7iaZlA/formResponse')`: link Google Form

I know there're some plugin to help you connect Contact Form 7 with Google Sheet, but I want it to connect with Google Form, not Google Sheet.